# Reverse engineer Amiga monitor files

Tags: driver, reverse-engineering, amiga

The files found in Devs:Monitors in AmigaOS, what do they contain?

What is their internal format?  How do you go about patching one or creating one from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Amiga program MonEd (http://aminet.net/package/driver/moni/MonEd3a) is an editor for these files. It comes with source, which may well indicate something about the structure.

It also notes:

> Then click on save to store this information in the TOOL TYPES of monitor which is stored in DEVS:Monitors/

which may have something to do with the file size.

Answer (score 3):

They are the monitor drivers for AmigaOS and contain the various parameters needed to interface the Amiga to different displays.  As far as the internal format goes, I've no idea, there may be something in the old RKM manuals or the Amiga Developer CD.

Comment: These things are very small too. Interesting that there is so little info about them.

Comment: I noticed that people on the http://www.Natami.net team apparently are reverse engineering them.